# Eclipse Executable from terminal

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, installation

Hey I downloaded the latest version of eclipse and extracted the folder and ran it using `./eclipse` everything worked fine. I was wondering if there is a way to just run eclipse or eclipse & from the terminal and eclipse will execute without going to the eclipse directory. I did it before when I used sudo apt-get to install eclipse but they don't have the latest version of eclipse. I am using linux btw and I have to navigate to the folder where I put eclipse every time I want to run it. If there is a obvious answer to the question I apologize for asking but I couldn't find anything on it. 
Thank you for any input.

Comment: Have you tried replacing dot with location of eclipse?

Comment: What distribution of linux? For [ubuntu](http://www.blogs.digitalworlds.net/softwarenotes/?p=54) or [centos](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-install-eclipse-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), you usually create "/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop" and then it's on your application launcher.

Comment: I would still have to have to navigate to the folder via the terminal with this method right?

Comment: Add that folder to your PATH in your `.bashrc`? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I'm running bodhi linux.

Comment: Enlightening. Add it to your PATH, and good luck. I haven't used e in a very long time.

Comment: Basically anyway I can run eclipse or eclipse& command from the terminal and it will launch eclipse instead of me navigating to it.

Comment: Awesome thanks I see what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, is normal that way to execute eclipse, eclipse does not install, is like a executable. You need use `./eclipse` always and its normal you need go to directory.
Why dont create a desktop launcer like [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-install-eclipse-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

Comment: How would I go about adding the C++ plugin would I just have to use a different eclipse which has C++?

Comment: Does that install the newest version?

Comment: The link provided was what I was looking for .. I really can't remember the chmod command, have to look for it each time...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash there is a file called .bashrc, enter the following commands:

```
$ cd ~
$ ls -a
```

If you look, you should see .bashrc, then you need to edit it using some text editor like nano:

```
$ nano .bashrc
```

Once inside nano, you need to create an alias. An alias is a global variable in bash that references another value, for instance:

```
 alias eclipse="/path/to/executable/eclipse"
```

This is create a variable called eclipse that when typed into the terminal, in any directory, will execute and run eclipse. So simply add that line, replacing /path/to/executable/eclipse with the actual path of the program.

Once that is done you can type eclipse anywhere in bash and it will work.

SIDE NOTE:
 If you don't want your terminal session to hang when you open eclipse, type an ampersand after eclipse:

```
$ eclipse &
```

This will run the program in the background, freeing up your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `.bashrc` file and modify the `PATH` environment variable to include the path where you installed Eclipse.

Also, you should consider adding a desktop launcher which you can just double-click to run Eclipse.